# How can I change where `live-server` opens without changing my default browser

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-live-server

I want to change where live-server opens, for example, I like using safari as my default browser, but every time I type `live-server` in the terminal it will open a window on safari. I know I can type `live-server --browser='google chrome'` but now I don't want to be typing that whole code to open in Chrome. I want to change it so that when I type `live-sever` it will open on chrome instead, I know I have to change that in the .json file but I'm not sure where it's located, or how to access it in the terminal. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use a npm script for that?

Comment: Is there a way to modify the file where the information in npm live-server exist?

Comment: Why do it the easy way when you can do it the hard way... live-server is open source. Go fork it and modify it like you want.

Comment: I do  apologize, I looked into npm script and it appears that’s the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution after searching on the internet and it' straightforward. You just have to change your selected browser from you pc settings. It worked for me I hope it will work for you too!

Answer (score 0):

I found two methods that will solve this. The first is to go into the live-server code and change where it opens to `google chrome`. The second which is much better IMO since you can do multiple options is as @Marc recommended, to use an npm script. A script will let you do multiple browsers. What I use now is the following script:
`"glive": "live-server --browser=\"google chrome\" --open=\"dist/index.html\"",`
The `--open='dist/html'"` is only needed if your file is in a folder